# same query from remote server and on server, different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a server called ERP-SERVER, and a server called SQLDEV-SERVER.
They both have a blob instance, but we never copy over the complete blob to the SQLDEV-SERVER as that would be too much data.

So when trying to access a file on our test server, it should first check if that file exists on the SQLDEV-SERVER, and if not check if the file exists on the ERP-SERVER.  This is where it goes wrong.  This piece of code (SQL) used to work but somewhere along the way it broke.  I have narrowed it down to the inter database query just returning completely different results.

so for instance i run this query on the ERP-SERVER instance in SQL management studio:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [erp-server].[Extranet_Blob].[dbo].[FileStorBlob]
```

this returns 223221 results.

When i run the same query on the SQLDEV-SERVER instance in SQL management studio, it returns 313 results.

It points to the same server and same database, yet a completely different count, which is why it is also not returning the files from the live environment when it is not found on the dev environment.

Any pointers as to where this problem could be situated?

Comment: Do you have multiple connected instances in SSMS? Try, in SQL Management studio to disconnect and reconnect again to the desired instance and execute the query again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look very carefully at your linked server definition. When you are running the query on SQLDEV-SERVER it is using the linked server definition of that name rather than necessarily the ERP_Server. Is it possible that someone has fiddled with the definition?

Comment: That was it, this instance was recently re-created and the linked server definition pointed to itself because it could not resolve